# Unable to get value in javascript for loop from model attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsp

I am trying to get a value from model attribute in javascript in for loop as below.

```
for(i=0; i <'${cartData.getTotalItems()}'; i++){

strItemName =" ${cartData.getEntries()[i].getProduct().getName()}";

}
```

I get strItemName=" " in above case. But when I replace i with 0 or 1 , I get the value. 
When tried something like

```
" ${cartData.getEntries()["+i+"].getProduct().getName()}";
```

it throws number format exception for Input String in that jsp page.
I am kind of stuck with this. Tried with single quotes etc but no luck.
Any guidance is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: replace i to String(i) ?try ?

Comment: Is there a reason for not doing this loop inside a method defined in CartData to return an ArrayList for productNames?

Comment: You are confusing client side and server side. Your loop is Javascript running in a browser, but you use the index `i` in an expression that's evaluated on the server. `i` is not in scope on the server. You're going to need to build a Javascript array out of the Java collection _before_ the page is received by the browser.